# Haaaaaaaaaaaaaats!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Stack Exchange last year did [an end of the year party](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) featuring special hats. They want to know if we want to do the same thing this year to our site. So, do we want hats?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes please!

I believe it should be fun enough, and if someone wouldn't want any of such harmless, fun kitsch and still display our plain, vanilla Stack Exchange beta design even during the festive season, then they will have an option to opt-out in settings. From mod message:

> **Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
> hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
> available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
> will go back into storage.**

[image]

### Hold on to your hats, we're going to ludicrous speed this December 16th!

---

#### Some more examples from last year:

[image]

---

#### BTW, another fun fact, in case you missed it before

[Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) is also available through a web address [**thefinalfrontier**.stackexchange.com](http://thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com). It just redirects to the usual address, substituting *"thefinalfrontier"* with *"space"*, so any URL on the main site should work (including your profile, questions etc.). Might be fun posting it on other sites, especially in December. :D

Comment: Will they do custom hats, specific to a site? Like space related hats for us?

Comment: @geoffc I don't think so, that would involve too much work, but I do expect they'll expand the selection from what it was last year, and perhaps some of those new ones will be space related too. At least a "propellerhead" (?) :}

Comment: Close enough.  Too many sites to do custom ones i guess.  Could we suggest hat icons to them?  I.e. Submit site specific ones?

Comment: Just submitted our official acceptance. They didn't do custom ones last year, despite attempting to do so on SFF.

Comment: At least, I should try participating here for **HATZZZ** :D

Answer (score 7):

### Yes yes yes yes yes!!!

We want hats! More importantly, the hats want *us*! It's such an obvious match that anyone can see clearly that we need hats!