# Winter Bash 2014 Hat Dash Yay or Nay?

Tags: discussion

Remember last year's [Haaaaaaaaaaaaaats!](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/49)? Stack Exchange is going to repeat it this year, and asked us if we want it on Space Exploration, too.

### What is it?

> Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site
> that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by
> completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions
> trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We
> track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard that looks
> something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to **all sites that choose to
> participate**. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra
> features to keep things fresh and exciting.
>
> **Some Details**
>
> This event will run from **15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015**. Users
> will be able to see their entire hat collection on
> [winterbash2014.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/). That site will also have a
> landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
> hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
> available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats
> will go back into storage**.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
> the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

---

**So what say you? *"Yay"* or *"Nay"* to a bit of [SEx.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) cosplay?**

We have till 1 December 2014 to decide, otherwise we're automagically **opted in** to the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just submitted the official acceptance to our hat overlords. We're getting hats:-)

Answer (score 9):

I for one welcome our Hat based overlords. As a respected member of this community I can be helpful in recruiting for their underground felt mines.